# Problema con procedimiento almacenado con loop

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de contratos de alquiler y quiero para cada uno insertar el primer dia del mes el recibo para que quede listo para imprimir. Pero el contrato de alquiler debe estar activo, es decir tener estado=1:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin_inmobiliaria`@`%` PROCEDURE `crear_recibos`()
BEGIN
declare xCodigo int;  
    DECLARE
            fFecha date;

DECLARE
    honorarios DECIMAL (10, 2);

DECLARE
    total DECIMAL (10, 2);
    FOR contrato IN (
        SELECT
            a.idContratos,
            a.deposito,
            a.fecha_crea,
            a.cuota,
            a.seguro,
            a.agua,
            a.honorarios,
            a.idpropietario,
            a.idinquilino,
            a.idpropiedad
        FROM
            contratos a
        WHERE
            a.estado = 1
    ) DO
    

SET honorarios = contrato.cuota (contrato.cuota *(contrato.honorarios / 100));


SET total = honorarios + contrato.cuota + contrato.seguro + contrato.agua;


SET fFecha = NOW();

INSERT INTO recibos (
    idContrato,
    fecha_crea,
    mes,
    ano,
    fecha_vencimiento,
    idpropietario,
    idinquilino,
    idpropiedad,
    cuota,
    seguro,
    agua,
    honorarios,
    total
)
VALUES
    (
        idContratos,
        fFecha,
        MONTH (fFecha),
        YEAR (fFecha),
        DATE_ADD(fFecha, INTERVAL 10 DAY),
        idpropietario,
        idinquilino,
        idpropiedad,
        cuota,
        seguro,
        agua,
        honorarios,
        total
    );

 
  set xCodigo= @@IDENTITY;
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo) VALUES ("VALOR DE CUOTA",cuota,idContrato,xCodigo);
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo) VALUES ("VALOR DE AGUA",cuota,idContrato,xCodigo);
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo) VALUES ("VALOR DE SEGURO",cuota,idContrato,xCodigo);
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo) VALUES ("VALOR DE HONORARIOS",cuota,idContrato,xCodigo);

END FOR;



END$$
```

Trabajo con MySQL, y me da error donde dice contrato.cuota, es decir no me toma los campos seleccionados del select.

Comment: Por favor, pásanos el dataset con phpMyAdmin->exportar, dejando algunos registros de muestra. De otra forma tendríamos que depurar tu código de cabeza o inventarnos tus tablas.

Comment: No resumas el error. Pon el error completo en la pregunta. Por ahora, no es claro qué quieres hacer en ese set porque no hay operación entre contrato.cuota y el paréntesis

Comment: ¿Aquí no deberías usar el alias: **`SET honorarios = a.cuota (a.cuota *(a.honorarios / 100));`** y lo mismo al setear `total`?

Comment: El problema esta en que falta el operando despues de cuota..los honorarios son la cuota mas un porcentaje faltaria el +.

Comment: Si no nos proporcionas el dataset, lo que obtienes con tu intento, el error y lo que querrías obtener, nos pones realmente difícil poder ayudarte. Al formular esta pregunta así, únicamente te has ayudado a ti mismo organizando tus ideas y poco más. En cualquier caso, me alegra que hayas podido solucionarlo.